# why use \0 to include highEndPoint as part of the sublist

Tags: java, subset, treeset

I saw the code below from java tutorial oracle. In order to count the number of words between `doorbell` (inclusive) and `pickle`(inclusive), the author added `\0` after the word `pickle`. I understand that the effect of adding `\0` after `pickle`, is that the word `pickle` is now included as part of the subset. But my question is, why use `\0`? Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
SortedSet<String> dictionary = new TreeSet<>(entire collection of words from a dictionary);
int count = dictionary.subSet("doorbell", "pickle\0").size();
System.out.println(count);
```

Edit:

Also, what happen if the variable `dictionary` is a reference to SortedSet? what should I do now if I want to include the highEndPoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subSet(a, b)` is inclusive of `a` but *exclusive* of `b`. Therefore if you want to find a subset that is inclusive of the upper bound `pickle`, you have to use the next possible string after `pickle` as the (exclusive) upper bound.

You can get this by adding the null character `\0` to the end of the string.

In Java, a `char` is "really" just an integer between `0` and `65535`, and the `compareTo` method of `String` sorts characters by these values. To see that `\0` is the smallest possible `char` value you can print its value like this:

```
 System.out.println((int) '\0');    // Prints 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comment! However, I was wondering why \0 is chosen to be used in this context? what does \0  mean? what other function does it serve? Could you please help me out? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @dzjustinli3 `'\0'` is just a special character called the null character. It is the smallest possible character from the point of view of the way strings are compared.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `\0` is the null character.  The next word in the ASCII dictionary from a lexigraphic point after the word `pickle` is `pickle\0`.  The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) for `SortedSet.subset()` has the following to say:

> Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements range from fromElement, inclusive, to toElement, exclusive.

In other words, if your code snippet were the following:

```
int count = dictionary.subSet("doorbell", "pickle").size();
```

then the word `pickle` would not appear in the subset.

A better example might be if you wanted to get all words of the form `pickles`, but nothing of the form `picklet` (ending in `t`), then you would use the following code:

```
int count = dictionary.subSet("doorbell", "picklet").size();
```

[Here is a link](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/null-character-ascii-code-0.html) to the ASCII character table.